# Replace Text set width, alignment, decimals from stored text form (receipt)

Tags: delphi, replace, receipt

I have at a database stored the form of my receipt and at the desired positions the flags to insert the values from my query.

```
@01                           @04

@27

USER:@07
TBLno :@08  /@61

@24        @25

$D:0
@10  @11                 @12
```

I have a table translating the '@' at the desired field name e.g. @10-QTY, @11-ITEM, @12-Price. "$I:0" is the mark that the line below will be the repeated vales such as the items. How I am going to replace them, and fill my form?

Comment: Shouldn't you have figured that out *before* you decided that was the way you were going to store your data?

Comment: I nowhere see `$I:0` - you may want to re-read your text and correct all the mistakes to make it halfway understandable. Also this is not _Firebird_ related. See [all existing questions related to Delphi and "replace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+replace)

Comment: Sorry I wrote $D:0 by mistake instead of $I:0. Actually I didn't made the form, is already at the system and I should replicate the outcome. I tagged also firebird because the DB is firebird.